# Can't evaluate at compile time - NIM

Tags: nim-lang

Hi I'm starting to play around with NIM

I get a "can't evaluate at compile time" error on this code:

```
import strutils

type
 Matrix[x, y: static[int], T] = object
  data: array[x * y, T]

var n,m: int = 0

  
proc readFile() =
  
  let f = open("matrix.txt")
  defer: f.close()

  var graph_size = parseInt(f.readline)
  var whole_graph: Matrix[graph_size, graph_size, int]
  

  for line in f.lines:
   for field in line.splitWhitespace:
    var cell = parseInt(field)
    whole_graph[n][m] = cell
    m = m + 1 
   n = n + 1
     


readFile()
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: The issue is that you are trying to do something at compile-time with information you only have at runtime.
When you compile your program, you do not know how many lines a file you might later read in will have, that is runtime information.
That information you only have when running the binary is what you put into graph_size.
Thus, graph_size is NOT known at compile time!
Meanwhile you require that x and y in your Matrix type are known at compile time by using `static`.

Comment: Since you try to use `graph_size` with them you are trying to tell the program "I do not know how long this will be, but the Matrix will have that size!"
That does not work. You're likely doing this because you want to use array, which requires that you know its length at compile-time. Since the size of the array that you want appears to rely on a later file size, your best move here is to use `seq` instead of `array` and remove the `static` bit on your Matrix type.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you absolutely positively need array in this scenario while not knowing its size at compile-time, you may want to rather swap to the seq type, whose size does not need to be known at compile-time.

Together with `std/enumerate` you can even save yourself the hassle of tracking the index with `n` and `m`:

```
import std/[strutils, enumerate]

type Matrix[T] = seq[seq[T]]

proc newZeroIntMatrix(x: int, y: int): Matrix[int] =
  result = newSeqOfCap[seq[int]](x)
  for i in 0..x-1:
    result.add(newSeqOfCap[int](y))
    for j in 0..y-1:
      result[i].add(0)

proc readFile(): Matrix[int] =
  let f = open("matrix.txt")
  defer: f.close()

  let graph_size = parseInt(f.readline)
  var whole_graph = newZeroIntMatrix(graph_size, graph_size)
  
  for rowIndex, line in enumerate(f.lines):
    for columnIndex, field in enumerate(line.split):
      let cell = parseInt(field)
      whole_graph[rowIndex][columnIndex] = cell
    
  result = whole_graph

let myMatrix = readFile()
echo myMatrix.repr
```

Further things I'd like to point out though are:

- `array[x * y, T]` will not give you a 2D array, but a single array of length x*y. If you want a 2D array, you would most likely want to store this as `array[x, array[y, T]]`. That is assuming that you know x and y at compile-time, so your variable declaration would look roughly like this: `var myMatrix: array[4, array[5, int]]`
- Your `Matrix` type has the array in its `data` field, so trying to access the array with that Matrix type needs to be done accordingly (`myMatrix.data[n][m]`). That is, unless you define proper `[]`and `[]=` procs for the Matrix type that do exactly that under the hood.